# Organizing a random list of objects in Python

Tags: python, sorting, grouping

So I have a list that I want to convert to a list that contains a list for each group of objects.

ie 
['objA.attr1', 'objC', 'objA.attr55', 'objB.attr4'] 
would return 
[['objA.attr1', 'objA.attr55'], ['objC'], ['objB.attr4']]

currently this is what I use:

```
givenList = ['a.attr1', 'b', 'a.attr55', 'c.attr4']
trgList = []
objNames = []
for val in givenList:
    obj = val.split('.')[0]
    if obj in objNames:
        id = objNames.index(obj)
        trgList[id].append(val)
    else:
        objNames.append(obj)
        trgList.append([val])
#print trgList
```

It seems to run a decent speed when the original list has around 100,000 ids... but I am curious if there is a better way to do this.  Order of the objects or attributes does not matter.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Saebin: your question belongs on our sister site, Stack Overflow, and will be migrated there shortly.  you will need to register your account here, register an account on Stack Overflow, and associate them together to regain ownership of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be better defined: what do you do when there is no property? What order do you want the final list as? What about duplicates?

A general algorithm would be to use a multi-map: a map that has multiple values per key.
You will then scan through the original list, separate each element into an "object" and "property", and then add a key-value pair for the object and property. At the end of this cycle, you will have a mapping from objects to set of properties. You can then iterate over this to build your final list.

You can use a third-party multimap or implement yourself by mapping into a sequence.

You might want to create a dummy property for cases when the object does not have a property.

Comment: Duplicates would not happen and order of the groups and their properties does not matter.  If no property is given with an object, a group would need still created, it just wouldn't contain properties (yet).

The biggest limitation I didn't mention is the original object.property string must be preserved... otherwise I will have to rebuild the object.property string when I go to pass it to other functions.  So although I could use something like a dictionary to store the results, ie d[object1=['attr1','attr2']], ultimately I need the object and property put back together for each property.